# Fitting a table to a page

Tags: tables

I'm new to LaTex and it seems like there's a high learning curve. I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering\settowidth\rotheadsize{Next concept/}
  \renewcommand\cellalign{cl}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \caption{Title}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c}
    \toprule\noalign{\vskip-1pt}\hline
    \diagbox[height=1.25\rotheadsize]{\raisebox{3ex}{Layers}}{\raisebox{-4ex}{Neurons}} & 10 & 20 & 64 \\
    \hline
    2 & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) \\
    4 & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) \\
    8 & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) \\
    12 & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) \\
    \hline\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

It's a bit hard to see, but it continues too much to the right which is my main concern. Is there an easy fix for this? I tried playing with the height and `arraystretch`, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: We need to see your page layout. Please extend your document fragment to complete, compilable document. In preamble should be loaded only to your table relevant packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Apparently your table is wider than `\textwidth`. Consequently it protrude right text border.
- What you can do:

  - Increase `\textwidth` by loading `geometry` package.
  - Redesign table so, that the first column is narrower. This can be done by omitting of `\diagbox` and introduce new row (see MWE below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Title}
    \label{tab:neurons}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{4}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Neurons} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-4}
Layers
    & 10 & 20 & 64 \\
    \midrule
2   & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) \\
4   & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) \\
8   & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) \\
12  & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) & (0.001, 0.008, 0.001, 0.001) \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

- By this change table has more "profesional" looks:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: @Mico, added. Now is better. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This looks way better